# Randomly generated integers in a list are the same

Tags: python, list, random

I'm having this problem with my script. I want to initialize a genetic algorithm, and in this case I want to give every first element in the row a random value between 200 and 400.

```py
import random

def InitiatePopulation(Population,AmountofSettings):
    Generation= [None]*Population
    sett = []
    for k in range(0,Population):
        for j in range(0,AmountofSettings):
            sett.append(300)
        Generation[k] = sett
    for _k in range(0, len(Generation)):
        Generation[_k][0] = random.randint(200,400)
        for _p in range(1, len(Generation[_k]),3):
            Generation[_k][_p] = 20
    return Generation
```

Whenever I run the code, all first values all are the same values. i tried adjusting the seed value, but that doesnt work. Because I have had problems in the past with for loops, the problem could be there was well. I understand the code isnt necessarily efficient, I just wanted to get to the creation of the population before the adjustment of the first setting variable to a random integer.

Here is the current output:

```py
[[221, 20, 300, 300, 20, 300, 300, 20, 300, 300, 20, 300],
[221, 20, 300, 300, 20, 300, 300, 20, 300, 300, 20, 300]]
```

The expected output would be the same, except with the 221 values being different from each other.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: How are you calling this method? Do you want the remainder of the values in the array to be the same across all rows?

Comment: Yes, it just concerns the first element only. I have instances which randomize the entire array using: ```Generation= [np.random.randint(0,1000,AmountofSettings).tolist() for _ in range(Population)]``` But that is not the goal right now. In the code of my question i would expect it to run ```Generation[_k][0] = random.randint(200,400)``` twice because it is in a loop in a different position of the array. What am I missing?

Comment: @DiederikHuijsman What output do you expect from this code?

Comment: @SharimIqbal As in the Question, I would expect the code ```Generation[_k][0] = random.randint(200,400)``` to be run twice, thus having two random ints between 200 and 400 at the first positions of the two lists. It adds only one random element ```221``` to both positions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the issue is that you're setting all of the elements of `Generation` to be the same list (i.e. referring to the same location in memory).

You need to reassign the list to a new empty list at the start of each iteration:

```
for k in range(0,Population):
    sett = []
    for j in range(0,AmountofSettings):
        sett.append(300)
    Generation[k] = sett
```

Comment: There is a problem in your code the length of the nested lists not the same.

Comment: thank you very much. this is exactly what I  was referring to. I think my problems with understanding how Python code changes references, rather than creating new values is still hard to grasp for me... :)

Comment: @SharimIqbal Fixed.

Comment: @DiederikHuijsman No problem! Happy to help. Remember to upvote useful answers and to accept the one you find most helpful.

Comment: thank you for pointing htat out. I have solved that error now allready :)

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark Yeah now works

Answer (score 1):

I realize that it was answered, I'm just providing a slightly optimized solution if you need it. I removed 2 `for` loops and now it's one loop with a list comprehension outside since it only needs to run once.

```py
import random

def InitiatePopulation(Population, AmountofSettings):
    Generation = []
    sett = [20 if (x-1) % 3 == 0 else 300 for x in range(AmountofSettings)]
    
    for _ in range(Population):
        _sett = sett.copy()
        _sett[0] = random.randint(200,400)
        Generation.append(_sett)
               
    return Generation

print(InitiatePopulation(2, 12))
```